# Is Blue screen a better choice than Green when shooting outdoor to reserve shadows?

Tags: greenscreen, bluescreen

I'm going to use Green screen on the floor in a sunny day outdoor shot.

With the shadows of characters reserved, I'm going to change the Green screen background to a stony texture.

I've found in some resources that for an outdoor shoot the Blue is a better option. But still I'm not sure. Any assurance?

[image]

Comment: Blue screen was mostly used for film work, because the high contrast film they used to do the alpha mask was sensitive only to blue light. Video, including digital video has most resolution in the green channel, so green screen works best with video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a good keyer it doesn't matter as much as it may have in the past, but in most cases green is the better choice. Which you choose depends more on where and with what content you do your keying. If you're using equal-band capture, recording and processing -- 4:4:4 for instance -- then it can be a tossup. But any encoding that limits chroma bandwidth -- 4:2:0, 4:1:1 etc, will favor green because there's more green in the highest bandwidth channel (luma consists of more than 50% green). More resolution + less noise = better keying.

I think using blue outdoors might be favored because natural light is much bluer than typical studio lighting, which reduces the noise in the blue signal. But I doubt there's a significant advantage, because noise is only one factor.

Comment: Great answer! But it also depends on the shot, when shooting in a forest, it might be better using blue screen.